# How to integrate "Webpack-Module-Federation" as well as "Brotli Compression" in react?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation, brotli

## **Below are the contents of webpack.config.js file:**

**The "...moduleFederationConfig" is creating a remote file but whenever I try to implement the any plugin the "...moduleFederationConfig" doesn't work. I have attached my approach below**

```
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const withModuleFederation = require('@nrwl/react/module-federation');
const moduleFederationConfig = require('./module-federation.config');


module.exports = withModuleFederation({
  ...moduleFederationConfig,
});
```

**This is how I am implementing "brotli compression" plugin. The problem is the brotli plugin is working fine now but moduleFederationConfig stopped creating remote file :**

```
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const withModuleFederation = require('@nrwl/react/module-federation');
const moduleFederationConfig = require('./module-federation.config');

module.exports = withModuleFederation({
  ...moduleFederationConfig,
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    // Update the webpack config as needed here.
    config.plugins.push(
      new CompressionPlugin({
        filename: "[path][base].br",
        algorithm: "brotliCompress",
        test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8,
        deleteOriginalAssets: false,
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
});
```